# SSL support for Here Maps Base plan

Tags: ssl, https, here-api

Does anyone know of a way to get maptiles over HTTPS/SSL without having an enterprise subscription?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just upgrade your code to use the 3.0 version of [Maps API for JavaScript](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics/overview.html), it offers https to all users.

When you initialise the `H.service.Platform` object, just set `useHTTPS` to `true`

```
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
      'app_id': '<your app id>',
      'app_code': '<your app code>',
      'useHTTPS': true
    });
```